# iOS Here Map SDK removal

Tags: ios

I was migrating iOS Here Map SDK to use Here Map Rest API instead, now everything got migrated to Rest API calls and I want to remove iOS Here Map SDK manually, which I made linkage manually followed by their office web site (https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple.html).
However, after I did so, I got compiling error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
 "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this? Was trying to scratch my head on this one for some time.

Comment: Look for `kReachabilityChangedNotification` in your code? Also doesn't it says the file where it is? You can find Reachability on the web in needed (pods, etc.)

Comment: I actually have SystemConfiguration.framework linked to Target, but still encounter the same issue. Wondering why it's still happening tho

Comment: Thanks @larme, I just download the file and put it in my project, and it worked.Wondering why if I still need to put Reachability.h and .m in my project even if I have SystemConfiguration.framework linked.

Comment: I didn't check, but I don't think that Reachability is in `SystemConfiguration.framework`. According to this one (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Reachability), Reachability needs `SystemConfiguration.framework`, but not the reverse.

Comment: Thank you @Larme, I am very surprised that Apple didn't have the replacement on their end and instead they asked developers to download it.
But really appreciate your help.